# What will be complexity of the below Insersion sort code?

Tags: sorting, time-complexity, insertion-sort, space-complexity, code-complexity

I have written the below code for the insertion sort. Instead of traditional approach I decided to write to code through function call. But I am unable to find the complexity of the code. Please help me to find the time and space complexity and how much is differ than the traditional approach.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(int ar_size, int *  ar){
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<ar_size; j++)
                printf("%d ", ar[j]);

        printf("\n");
}
void insertion(int ar_size, int *  ar, int p) {
    int last = p, j;
    int v = ar[last];

    for(int i=last; i>=0; i--){
        if(ar[i-1] > v){
            ar[i] = ar[i-1]; 
        }
        else{
            ar[i] = v;
            break;
        }     
    }
    printArray(ar_size, ar);
}

void insertionSort(int ar_size, int *  ar) {
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<ar_size; i++){
        insertion(ar_size, ar, i);
    }
}

int main(void) {

   int _ar_size;
scanf("%d", &_ar_size);
int _ar[_ar_size], _ar_i;
for(_ar_i = 0; _ar_i < _ar_size; _ar_i++) { 
   scanf("%d", &_ar[_ar_i]); 
}

insertionSort(_ar_size, _ar);

   return 0;
}
```

Below is the traditional approach for the insertion sort:

```cs
void InsertionSort(int a[], int n)
{
    int i,j, temp;
    for(i=0; i<=n-1; i++)
    {
        temp = a[i];
        j = i;
        while(a[j-1] > temp && j>=1)
        {
            a[j] = a[j-1];
            j--;
        }
        a[j] = temp;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Maybe I dont get what is your problem, but you could simply measure the time it takes for increasing size of input to see what is the complexity.

Comment: @Kikit. Consider posting this on the Code Review stack exchange. That site is better suited to have people look at your existing working code and give the feedback that you're looking for.

Comment: @matrixugly . is there any way to transfer this problem to Code Review Stack Exchange or I have to repost there ?

Comment: @tobi303 . I simply want the time and space complexity of the my code.

Comment: I would just measure it

Answer (score 0):

Your code's time complexity is still O(n²). Moving the inside of the for loop into the `insertion` function doesn't change the complexity. If you copy and paste the contents of your `insertion` function into the loop that calls it, there will be no difference in the running time of your code (in fact, the compiler probably does exactly this for you at compile time as part of optimisation).

If you look at your code this way, you will notice that it is essentially functionally equivalent to the reference code you provided.

1. The reference code has an outer loop from 0 to the array size, as does yours.
2. The inner loop of the reference code loops from the current position in the array to the beginning, or until it finds a smaller element. Your code calls a function that proceeds to do exactly this, just in more lines of code.

Functionally, your code is essentially identical to the reference insertion sort implementation; both have the same time complexity, and would sort the array in exactly the same series of steps. However, the reference implementation *might be slightly faster*, simply because it doesn't do as much variable assignment, and avoids using a function call.

Compiling with optimisations enabled (as they are by default) should render both pieces of code almost identical.

Comment: Having said that, the reference code is much shorter, and clearer in what it does. Having significantly longer code that does exactly the same thing in a more confusing way is rarely a good thing.